# executing Jmeter on a AIX box

Tags: jmeter

I have developed scripts with Jmeter 5.1.1 in Windows machine. I want to execute those JMeter scripts in AIX box.

Please let me know the process to execute JMeter scripts in AIX box.

Thanks
Raghav

Answer (score 0):

As per Apache [JMeter project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/):

> The Apache JMeter™ application is open source software, a **100% pure Java application** designed to load test functional behavior and measure performance.

So given you have Java version 8 or higher installed on your AIX machine - you should be able to download and install JMeter there without any issues and execute the script, you created on your Windows machine normally. Check out [Identifying the Java versions and Java installation locations for an AIX system](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ibm-java-aix-faq-identifying-java-versions-and-java-installation-locations-aix-system) article for more details on how to check existing Java installation and install Java if it is not there.

Also be aware that according to [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article you should always be using the latest version of JMeter (which is [JMeter 5.3](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-3-released-td5728863.html) as of now) so probably right now it's the best time to perform the upgrade. You can always obtain the latest stable JMeter version from [JMeter Downloads](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page